# How to calculate a value into a own column without having to call the database for each record

Tags: java, grid, vaadin

I am trying to load data to the grid from another database table.

My grid is created from `User` entity

```
private Grid<User> grid = new Grid<>(User.class, false);
```

`User` has several columns like

```
private Long userId;
private String username;
private String email;
.
.
.
```

The `User` contains the record identifier from the second table (entity) too:

```
private Long organizationId;
```

So I added columns to the grid:

```
grid.addColumn(User::getUserId).setAutoWidth(true).setHeader("id");
grid.addColumn(User::getUsername).setAutoWidth(true).setHeader("login");
```

And I created my "own" column which using data from another table (entity):

```
 grid.addColumn(user -> organizationService.findOrganizationNameByOrganizationId(user.getOrganizationId()).setAutoWidth(true).setHeader("organization name");
```

But problem is, that loading is very slow, because `User` table has about `500 000 rows` and it send query to the database for each row ...

Is possible to load `organization name` by `organization id` defined in `user entity` in batch e.g. ?

Comment: Why don't you join the tables and let the DB do the heavy lifting?

Comment: @cfrick it will be the second way, if this solution is can't be reached ...

Comment: Workaround: Could you avoid showing that info immediately in favour of a lazy loading via a button click (or via https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/grid/#item-details)? If that's not feasible, you can cache the results from the other table in the column renderer so you don't have to call the database per each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'd not bother with with enriching rows, in that way, if
I don't have to.  If the solution is as simple as just joining the data
in the DB, creating a view, ... then just do that.

Yet, there are times, this has to be done efficiently, because the data
to enrich does not come from the same source.

I think the best place to do that, is as part of the lazy loading of the
data.  Once you hold the stream in hand for the currently loaded page,
you can `map` over the stream and enrich the data, or do an batch load
etc.  Pick what is most efficient.

If you have to do that a lot, make sure to provide useful tools inside
your repositories; for quickly adding things just for one grid, you can
as well highjack the DataProvider or it's successor.

Following an example (note the `XXX`):

```
@Route("")
class GridView extends Div {
    GridView() {
        add(new Grid<User>(User).tap {
            setItems({ q ->
                // XXX: this materializes the stream first to get all
                //      unique organizationId:s, batch-load the
                //      Organization, and finally transform the User
                def users = FakeUserRepo.page(q.offset, q.limit).toList()
                def orgaMap = FakeOrganizationRepo.batchLoad(users*.organizationId.toSet())
                users.stream().map {
                    it.organizationName = orgaMap[it.organizationId].name; it
                }
            }, { q ->
                FakeUserRepo.count()
            })
        })
    }
}

@TupleConstructor
class Organization {
    Integer id
    String name
}

class FakeOrganizationRepo {

    public static final Map<Integer, Organization> ORGANIZATIONS = (0..<5).collectEntries { [it, new Organization(it, "Organization $it")] }

    static Map<Integer, Organization> batchLoad(Set<Integer> ids) {
        ORGANIZATIONS.subMap(ids)
    }
}

@TupleConstructor
class User {
    Integer id
    String name
    Integer organizationId
    String organizationName
}

class FakeUserRepo {

    public static final Collection<User> USERS = (1..500_000).collect {
        new User(it, "User $it", it % FakeOrganizationRepo.ORGANIZATIONS.size())
    }

    static int count() {
        USERS.size()
    }

    static Stream<User> page(int offset, int limit) {
        USERS.stream().skip(offset).limit(limit)
    }

}
```